# Make hash calculation faster

Tags: java

I have this code here, and I need to modify it. It works, but because of how "hash" is calculated it is slow. I need to make it faster just by writing the calculation differently. Any ideas will be much appreciated. I have to add that right now this code uses polynomial method and it needs to be changed to division method.

```
    private int myhash(Key key) 
        {
        int hash = 7;
        String k = (String) key; //here we assume keys are strings.
        int base=31;
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length(); i++)

                  hash=(int)Math.round(( Math.pow(31, k.length()-i-1 ))) * k.charAt(i) + hash;

        hash=Math.abs(hash) % m;
        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: if you "assume" it's a `String`, why not get the hashCode from that?

Comment: If your want String's hash code algorithm, it's right there in the javadocs. Also, Sting is a final class, meaning you can't extend it, so we can know that Keys are never subclasses of Sting -- unless they String class is something other than `java.lang.String`, which would be a bad idea.

Comment: Eugene, do you mean using key.hashCode()?

Comment: did you read the previous comment? what is your `Key` anyway?

Comment: Key is a key in hash map with a word from a file.The whole program is a word count. It is just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not assume that Key is string, as no class can extend String in Java. Maybe the map should be defined as

```
Map<String, String>
```

No need to reinvent the wheel as there is an implementation of hashcode that can be called using string.hashCode() function.

The implementation can be found below and it's available in the JDK source code.

```
int h = 0;
if (string.length() > 0) 
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        h = 31 * h + string.charAt(i);
    }
}
return h;
```

It seems that your code compute a different kind of hash

To improve it you could compute and store powers of 31 in a distinct variable and use it instead of using the expensive pow()